# Vuex state not updating after mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to set some values to the state using a mutation in my Vue/Vuex application.

**component.vue**

```
created() {
    let clubId = {'clubId': 31};
    this.$store.dispatch(
    "clubConfiguration/getClub",
    clubId 
  );
}
```

**action.js**

```
getClub(context, payload) {
    ApiService().post('/club/getSingleClub', {
        "ClubId": payload.clubId
    })
     .then(res => {
          context.commit('GET_CLUB_INFORMATION', res.data.data[0]);
     })
     .catch(err => {
           console.log(err)
    })
}
```

**mutation.js**

```
GET_CLUB_INFORMATION(state, payload) {
    state.Name = payload.Name
    console.log(state);
}
```

**state.js**

```
Name: '',
mapLocation: { lat: 39.585693, lng: 2.622868, zoom: 18 },
courts: [
    {
        id: 0,
        number: 1,
        name: 'Court 1',
        map: null
    }
]
```

Now, in the console.log i have in the mutation shows that 'Name' in the payload have attached to the state along with other state properties. But when i am checking in the Vue dev tools or tried to access the `state.Name` from the component it shows the `state.Name` property in the state as `undefined`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: let me know if the answer below works, it worked for me when I just passed the name, make sure you pass the name here:

context.commit('GET_CLUB_INFORMATION', res.data.data[0]);

maybe 'res.data.data[0].name', also you might add an 

if (res.data.data[0] && res.data.data[0].name), just for precaution

Comment: What does the data returned by the server look like? How are you accessing `Name` in the component? If you check `mapLocation` and `courts` do you see their initial state populated correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Your mutation should be

```
 GET_CLUB_INFORMATION(state, payload) {
  state.Name = payload
  console.log(state);
 }
```

cause you are passing just the name, not the whole payload